# Issue in populating Google GeoChart Map from a PHP array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-visualization

I have a PHP array of country names -

```
<?php 
$countries_array = array("Russia", "Australia", "Chile");
?>
```

I need to show these countries on map via the [Google Geochart map](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) in Javascript and using this code -

```
function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');

<?php 
    foreach ($countries_array as $cty) {
        echo "data.addRow(['Country', " . $cty . "]);";
    }
?>

    var options = {backgroundColor: '#E7F2F4'};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I guess I'm passing the countries array in a wrong way, because the map doesn't show these countries.
How can I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note PHP serves `$countries_array` so you need to be within PHP script tags to output the array. It is probably easier to add each data using `addRow()`, it makes the syntax simpler.

```
function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');

<?php 
    foreach ($countries_array as $cty) {
        print "data.addRow(['" . $cty . "']);" . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>

  var options = {backgroundColor: '#cccccc'};
  var chart = new   google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: still not working. the map doesn't appear now. updated my question with my code @suspectus

Comment: thanks. your answer works with just s small modification. by removing 'Country', from - print "data.addRow(['Country', '" . $cty . "']);" . PHP_EOL;